# What is the impact of changing the topic size for a premium Azure Service Bus?

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

We are using a premium Azure Service Bus and we are getting close to our current limit of 5 GB into our current limit of 5 GB as the maximum topic size. We are considering increasing it to 10GB or 20GB but we cannot see what the implications will be from a cost and/or performance perspective?

Will an increase of topic size introduce extra costs or affect the general performance of the service bus (we are currently using one message unit).

[image]

Comment: Check the `Integration Section` in  [Azure Pricing Calculator](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/pricing/calculator/?&ef_id=CjwKCAiAnZCdBhBmEiwA8nDQxa3H6Opw2YWY5HXpjoHdeXRLMUP7s4FxIkIuSzJFoBWyo0fR6ybk5xoCTRYQAvD_BwE:G:s&OCID=AIDcmmf1elj9v5_SEM_CjwKCAiAnZCdBhBmEiwA8nDQxa3H6Opw2YWY5HXpjoHdeXRLMUP7s4FxIkIuSzJFoBWyo0fR6ybk5xoCTRYQAvD_BwE:G:s&gclid=CjwKCAiAnZCdBhBmEiwA8nDQxa3H6Opw2YWY5HXpjoHdeXRLMUP7s4FxIkIuSzJFoBWyo0fR6ybk5xoCTRYQAvD_BwE)

Comment: Hi @Harshitha - I have tried to look at the pricing calculator but I cannot find anything relevant when looking at the premium version of the service bus (other than the option of having more than one message unit).